# Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_pipe_open - apm commands

Tags: npm, atom-editor

Trying to execute `apm install language-elm` but getting an EINVAL error listed below

Tried reinstalling the atom application, but still hasn't worked

```
apm install language-elm
net.js:264
    this._handle.open(fd);
                 ^

Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, uv_pipe_open
    at new Socket (net.js:264:18)
    at createWritableStdioStream (internal/process/stdio.js:178:16)
    at process.getStdout [as stdout] (internal/process/stdio.js:19:14)
    at console.js:420:19
    at NativeModule.compile (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:233:7)
    at Function.NativeModule.require (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:155:18)
    at setupGlobalConsole (internal/bootstrap/node.js:367:41)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:86:7)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:572:3)
```

Expecting the command to execute as normal

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to either:

- remove the modules directory of the app you are trying to build and run npm again to see if this is not a result of inconsistent node state
- or try this with yarn, to see if this is npm specific?